# Are MySQL ENUMS intended for use with CakePHP or should I avoid them?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, enums, conventions

Thing is, I don't see these ENUMs producing pull-down menus in CakePHP scaffolding, so I'm thinking CakePHP might advise against it, but I can't find any documentation on the matter.

Anyone know whether or not to use ENUMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this question, straight from [trac.cakephp.org,](http://trac.cakephp.org/) [ticket #2169.](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/2169)

> [yes, we are dropping support for enums](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/2169)

Comment: Why did they do this?  Anyone?  Bueller?

Comment: Travis: The answer is in the link. ENUMs only work in MySQL. That's why they are dropping them.